# Android - Animation resets after list update - monodroid and mvvmcross

Tags: listview, animation, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am implementing a "slidein" menu similar to the one found in the facebook app - see the images. It is implemented using mono droid and mvvmcross.

The way I am achieving this, is to have two layouts and with an animation the slide out/slide in effect is achieved. I simply slide out the layout "on top" and the other comes to light- this words as a charm. 
The second layout contains a table in which it is possible to do a selection(the square). When pushed it reloads a checkmak instead of the empty square. However when this happens, the entire view reloads back to zero - it seems that the entire view is reloaded ignoring the new location(offscreen) of layout 1.

How can this be? Do you have any suggestions or comment. Is it possible to avoid reloading of the entire view leaving only the table to reload?

Any help is highly appreciated.

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

Comment: can you test this without any databinding - ie is this an mvvm issue or just a monodroid/android issue? can you provide a simple repo as a repro (not sure I understand your situation even with the excellent screenshots)

Comment: Hi Stuart, I tried without the databinding between the cell's imageview(the one containing the square image) and the viewmodel. This resulted in the imageview did not get updated, and the entire view was not "reset" as before. It seems only to happen when the tablecells ui(in this case imageview) is updated. So it seems that the updated imageview in the tablecell causes the view to reload or maybe it just redraws the entire view ignorering the new location of the top layout.

Comment: I don't think I can help you from what you've posted. The good news is that plenty of people have used SlidingMenu views fine with MvvmCross. From the images and text you've posted I've no idea what menu control you are using or what code you are executing within the menu. Maybe try reproducing your effect in a smaller sample where you can share significantly more detail and code. If not, then get in and debug it - what events are firing where. Sorry I can't help more.

Comment: Hi Stuart, its ok, I will get down and dirty, and if the issue persists I will create a small sample project with the error.